# Load distribution in LoadRunner

Tags: c, performance-testing, loadrunner

I want to **control TPH / TPS using HP LoadRunner**. In JMeter we can do it by using **constant throughput timer** or if any one has alternative ways then please share.

For example:

1. Transaction A-Login (100 TPH)
2. Transaction B-Search Product (1000 TPH)
3. Transaction C-Add Product in cart (200 TPH)
4. Transaction D-Payment (200 TPH)
5. Transaction E-Logout (100 TPH)

Comment: - Have you been through LoadRunner training, been through the LoadRunner tutorial or read the books related to run time settings? - What have you tried? When you conducted your trial you likely had a hypothesis for how your changes would work, how did the observed behavior differ from your Hypothesis on action for your changes?

Comment: Your answer is covered in the training material for LoadRunner, both the instructor delivered, the tutorial and the documentation related to the use of the run time settings

Answer (score 0):

If all of these transactions are in different scripts, no problem, since you can set different pacing and run time settings to each script.

I assume your problem is that all of these transactions are in the **same script**. In this case, the only solution is to create a parameter in your script, let's call this parameter `iterator`, and set its type as **iteration number**. This way, this parameter will be with value 1 in the first iteration, value 2 in the second, etc. etc.

Now you can use this parameter before calling each transaction.

Let's say your maximum TPH is 1,000. Then set the script's run time settings pace to 1,000 TPH. But if you want a certain transaction to run less than that, let's say only 100 TPH, then you need to run it every 10th iteration only (1,000 / 100 = 10).

To do that, in your script, you can use `iterator % 10`:

```
// Cast the iterator parameter to an int
var i;
i = atoi(lr_eval_string("{iterator}"));

// This  will run 100 TPH
if ((i % 10) == 0) 
{
     lr_start_transaction("Login");

     // Do login
     ...

     lr_end_transaction("Login", LR_AUTO);
}
```

And another example, to run 200 TPH, you can use `iterator % 5`:

```
// This  will run 200 TPH
if ((i % 5) == 0) 
{
     lr_start_transaction("Add Product");

     // Do Add Product
     ...

     lr_end_transaction("Add Product", LR_AUTO);
}
```